# VBA to Merge Two Cells that will always be in cells 2 rows beneath the last row with data in it

Tags: vba, excel

I am relative new to VBA. I am writing a macro and need to merge two cells in columns C and D that will always appear in the second row beneath the last row with data in it. The script below is what I am trying to do, but continue to receive an error message. Any assistance or ideas is appreciated.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C:D" & Lastrow + 2).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
```

Answer (score 4):

`"C:D" & LastRow + 2` is not a valid `Range` reference. And no need to `Select`.

```
With Range("C" & LastRow + 2 & ":D" & LastRow + 2)
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
    .Merge
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

No disrespect to @BigBen, But your recorded code can be cleaned up even more, most of the code added is default code and can be removed. Also, your range can be cleaned up using `Cells`, `Offset`, and `Resize`.

```
With Cells(lRow, 3).Offset(2).Resize(, 2)
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
End With
```

Comment: I agree :) Most of it is default. I also left out a recommendation to fully qualify the workbook and worksheet.